# Speech Recognition with opening programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()

def get_audio():
    global RealAudio
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        RealAudio = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(RealAudio)
        commands_audio()
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Impossibole to understand.\n")
        get_audio()

def start_function():
    global Discord
    try:
        if Discord == 'False':
            os.system('cd D:\\Program\\Steam\Steam.exe')

if 'open Steam' in RealAudio:
    Discord = False
    start_function()
    get_audio()
```

I just started on my voice program. I always get the error message ´Could not find the specific directory´. I want it to open the program Steam.exe.

Comment: I don't see your main function here. What line does it fail?

Comment: It fails at: os.system('cd D:\\Program\\Steam\Steam.exe')